# UITableView sectionIndexTitles compressed on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, ios7

`UITableView`'s section indexes compress on iOS 7, even though there's ample space (this happens on the iPad). On iOS 6 everything's fine:

[image: iOS 7 section indexes vs iOS 6 section indexes]

This only happens when in landscape.

The `UITableView` is inside a container view, since I have a `UISearchBar` with a `UISearchDisplayController` above the table view, not as its header, but fixed under the `UINavigationBar`.

Anyone know how can I avoid the `sectionIndexTitles` compression?

Comment: I am having the same problem. It seems in my case only 29 items can fit into the index in landscape in iOS7. In iOS 6 I have no problem with 36 items (A-Z + 0-9) in the index. I will try to modify the index font to accomodate more items.

Comment: It makes no sense. Why would they limit it to 29? Haven't found a solution yet, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until iOS6, you could enumerate the subViews of the tableview and tinker with the view that had className UITableViewIndex. Like this:

```
for(UIView *aView in [tableView subviews]) 
   NSLog(@"View:%@",aView);
   if([[[aView class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"]) 
       aView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0];
```

In iOS7 Apple changed the view hierarchy and introduced a UITableViewWrapperView as a direct subview of the UITableView that effectively hides all implementation details. It has no subviews. No tinkering anymore.
So I guess the only thing left is file this as a bug.

Comment: I'd have to concur. I'll select this as the correct answer, for now. Thanks.

Comment: I have file a bugreport at Apple, with number 15175436.